Options on SOFR Futures + SONIA futures modelling
I am modelling options on SOFR and SONIA futures using the Bachelier model (under a first approximation). The discounted price for a call option is
$$
C(K) = e^{-rT}[(F_0 - K)N(d) + \sigma\sqrt{T}n(d)]
$$
The undiscounted price for a put option is
$$
P(K) = e^{-rT}[(K - F_0)N(-d) + \sigma\sqrt{T}n(d]
$$
where $K, F_0, \sigma, T, r$ is the strike, forward price, volatility time to expiry and continuously compounded interest rate, respectively. $N(d)$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution, $n(d)$ is the PDF and $d=(F_0 - K)/\sigma\sqrt{T}$.
[The above was taken from the paper A Black–Scholes user’s guide to the Bachelier model: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.08686]
I am trying to understand what value of $r$ to take (and why) and would like an example. Let us take the SOFRZ25 call option on a 3M SOFR Future SOFRZ25 Comdty. The details on date 2024-06-13
$K=97, T=1.49863, F=96.135, \sigma=1.21866$
The expiry date of option is 2025-12-12
The maturity date of the underlying future is 2025-09-16
QUESTIONS:

What value of $r$ shall I input to price the option?


I read in a few places it is the overnight rate
so can I use implied rate from the SOFR Future i.e. the Final Settlement Price Rate rate $R=100-F=100-96.135=3.865 % $. Use the following formula and invert to find $S_i = r$?

 
where:
x = the number of SOFR rates determined in the Accrual Period.
N = the number of calendar days in the Accrual Period.
Ai = the overnight return factor in respect of the ith SOFR rate of the Accrual Period,
Si = the ith SOFR rate of the Accrual Period

What nuances do I need to consider for mid curves?

